# T-SQL RAISERROR WITH NOWAIT Only Printing One Character Instead Of Whole String

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I've got several T-SQL Stored Procedures, where I am using RAISERROR with a Severity parameter of 0 to print progress messages to the output window. I am already using WITH NOWAIT to ensure the messages get printed immediately.

However, no matter what string i pass to RAISERROR, only the first character is being printed to the screen.

For example:

```
RAISERROR('Profiles Complete', 0, 1) WITH NOWAIT
```

only prints a single 'P' to the screen.

Does anybody know why this is or how I can fix it?

Thanks very much,

Martyn.

Comment: Unable to reproduce it here (even with a succeeding `WAITFOR` statement to ensure I'm seeing the result *during* execution rather than when the batch completes)

Comment: Is your error message a literal string as you showed in your example, or is it a variable? You mentioned 'passing' a string to RAISERROR, which makes me think you might have a char or varchar variable declared without a length. In that case, it would have length 1 by default so you would only get the first letter of your error.

Comment: Equally unable to reproduce. Please show how you're using the proc eg are you catching the error message string into a field that is defined as varchar without a length?

Comment: Pondlife: I'm using literal strings exactly as shown in the example, however, I did try using variables and the same thing happened with only the first character being printed. Although, when I did try the variable, I did declare it without size, so, I will try the variable again, but declare it with a size this time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When a variable is declared as char with no length, the length defaults to 1.

```
DECLARE @c char
SET @c = 'Profiles Complete'
PRINT @c
```

Output:

```
P
```

Comment: Thanks very much, changed to using variable with a declared length. All working now!

Comment: Brilliant decision by SQL Server designers to make 1 the default length of CHAR and VARCHAR type, and to silently truncate a longer string that's assigned to a CHAR or VARCHAR.